# Replace specific symbols between curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string **"This $.%^ is my {correct.!string*?:%^}"**

I am trying to use javascript's string.replace method with a regex to remove a few specific characters within curly braces (**!  * ? : % . ^**)

My desired output is

**"This $.%^ is my {correctstring}"**

Essentially I am trying to match certain symbols only if they are within brackets.

If regex and .replace() is insufficient in this case, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? E.g. how would you remove the specific characters if it were not for the "inside curly braces" part? How would you attempt to get the text inside the curly braces? Note that my assumption is, that curly braces are never nested - e.g. the string "{{}}" would be invalid. If that assumption is not correct, that would also be interesting to know.

Comment: .replace(/(\.|\^|\*|\?|:|!|%|\$)/g, "") is how I would do it if brackets were not a constraint

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.replace` optionally takes a replacer function:

```js
console.log("This $.%^ is my {correct.!string*?:%^}"
  .replace(
    /\{([^}]*)\}/g,
    (fullMatch, group1) => `{${group1.replace(/\.|\^|\*|\?|:|!|%|\$/g, "")}}`
  )
);
```

Note that if you use the new lookbehind (not supported in many implementations yet), you could even use:

```js
//Works e.g. in the current chrome version already:
console.log("This $.%^ is my {correct.!string*?:%^}"
  .replace(
    /(?<=\{)[^}]*(?=\})/g,
    fullMatch => fullMatch.replace(/\.|\^|\*|\?|:|!|%|\$/g, "")
  )
);
```

It is important, that there can never be any nested curly brackets. The before mentioned code does not work for e.g. "{{}}", as nested structures can, in the general case, not be parsed with regex.

Answer (score 0):

here an example code to replace selected special characters

```js
    var str = "This $.%^ is my {correct.!string*?:%^}";
    // extract the interested text block
    var strArr = str.replace(/[{}]/g,'**myUniqueSubstring**').split('**myUniqueSubstring**');

//console.log(strArr[1].replace(/[(!*?:%.^)]/g, ''));
// matching all the occurrences of selected special characters
var finalString = strArr[0] + "{" + strArr[1].replace(/[(!*?:%.^)]/g, '') + "}";

console.log(finalString);
```